# Entity-Framework: How to create a model from a disconnected dataset?

Tags: entity-framework, model, dataset

Using EF, is it possible to create the model from a disconnected dataset?

Keep in mind that there is no "database", only a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes, but in practice probably no.

i.e. it is possible but it would be a lot of work.

Essentially you could write a Provider that talks to a DataSet.

This however would not be trivial, check out [Jarek's post on Wrapping Providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) for more information.

Hope this helps

Alex